# How can I prevent an unwind segue from UITabBar?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, segue

I have a Show segue that is embedded in a UITabBarController. I want to prevent an unwind segue when I tap the currently selected tab unless a certain condition is met. I've tried using `shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier` and `canPerformUnwindSegueAction` but neither appear to be triggered when unwinding in this way.

Comment: How exactly have you set it up? Is one tab bar button set to do an unwind?

Comment: At the moment the tab bar is implemented without a custom class. Under one of the tabs, I have a Show segue. The view that this segue leads into maintains the tab bar at the bottom. When I am in that new view, I can tap the currently selected tab in the tab bar and it will automatically unwind the segue back to the first view. I think this is just part of the built in functionality of a tab bar.

Comment: I have updated my answer with more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by unwind segue on a tab bar, but if you want to prevent a tab change, there is a delegate function on `UITabBarController` for that purpose.

Add the protocol to your tab bar class.

```
@interface YourTabbarViewController () <UITabBarControllerDelegate>

@end
```

Assign the delegate, then later implement the function.

```
@implementation YourTabbarViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.delegate = self;
}

- (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {

    if (preventTabChange)
        return NO;

    return YES;
}
```

---

UPDATE

OK, assuming you have set up relevant parts as on this picture, and you want to prevent the unwind from B to A if certain conditions are met. My solution as described above will work.

[image]

As you will get a query/notification whenever the *Navigation Controller* is about to become active, you could create your own sub-class of that to hold whatever information you need to decide if it should be allowed to show or unwind from a sub-view controller. In that case your prevention could look like this (expanding the `shouldSelectViewController` above):

```
- (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {

    if ([viewController isKindOfClass:[YourNavigationController class]]) {
        if ([(YourNavigationController *)viewController preventUnwind])
            return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Note that I purposely chose `preventUnwind` as a flag in your custom class to say what to do. This will default to `NO` when you move *to* the view controller, and thus allowing that.

Don't forget to set `YourTabbarViewController` as the class for the *Tabbar View Controller* and `YourNavigationController` as the *Navigation Controller* in the picture.

Comment: Thank you, I am now able to prevent the unwind. Is there a way I can get a defining attribute from the viewController parameter so I can tell if I want to block the segue to it? For example, is there a way I could check the name of the view class?

Comment: The viewController is your sub-class of a navigation controller. Where exactly do you have the information that decides if you should prevent unwind? In A or B or elsewhere?

Comment: I think this may be what you are doing in your first if statement but I can't get Xcode to accept a custom navigation controller class in the check. I have a navigation controller that is connected on the storyboard and does turn purple in the text. However Xcode keeps giving me an "Unknown Receiver" error.

Comment: Perhaps you forgot to import the header at the top of the file? I mean, import the custom navigation controller .h file in the tabBar controller that the above test resides in.